# How can I change second background-image url with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a element with following style:

```
.element {
    background: transparent url(backgroundimage1.png) no-repeat,
        transparent url(backgroundimage2.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Is it possible to change only the second background url using JavaScript or jQuery without a lot of code?

Comment: Try this: `$('.element').css('background', 'transparent url(backgroundimage1.png) no-repeat, transparent url(newimage.png) no-repeat');`

Comment: @sfandler I hope this answer works for you, if it does please mark it as correct :D.

Comment: @Zoheiry Oh, yea thanks.. I upvoted but somehow forgot to accept the answer haha.

Comment: @sfandler Thanks, feel free to ask me anything at anytime ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible with a little string manipulation using jQuery.

```
var first_background = $(".element").css('background').split(',')[0];
var second_background = $(".element").css('background').split(',')[1];
var new_background = //add new background here.
$(".element").css('background', first_background + ',' + new_background);
```

And you're done.